Angular auth bug guard and interceptor
I want to do token-based authorization with angular, but I have a bug like this
I can protect pages with auth guard if the token has not exploded, but I cannot use the interceptor because auth guard protects pages on a per page basis while the interceptor protects http requests
so I can't create a new token with refresh token and it logins when the acces token explodes
how can I solve this bug
Auth.guard.js
export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);
  if (!authService.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("User not authenticated, redirecting to login");
    router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

Auth.interceptor.js
import { HttpInterceptorFn, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpContextToken } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { catchError, of, switchMap } from "rxjs";


export const AuthInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const authSvc = inject(AuthService);



  if (req.context.get(IS_PUBLIC)) {
    return next(req);
  }

  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
  if (accessToken) {
    const authRequest = addAuthorizationHeader(req, accessToken);
    return next(authRequest).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          return authSvc.refreshToken().pipe(
            switchMap((newAccessToken) => {
              if (newAccessToken) {
                const authRequestWithNewToken = addAuthorizationHeader(req, newAccessToken.data.accessToken);
                return next(authRequestWithNewToken);
              } else {
                authSvc.logout();
                return of();
              }
            })
          );
        }
        authSvc.logout();
        return of();
      })
    );
  } else {
    authSvc.logout();
    return of();
  }
};

const addAuthorizationHeader = (req: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) => {
  return req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
  });
};

export const IS_PUBLIC = new HttpContextToken(() => false);`

i think you could try to add a flag in auth service and setting it in refresh token and you can in guard to check this flag and based on it you can make your redirections

If the token exploded while checking authService.isAuthenticated(), I will recreate it with refresh token
